# Measure for normal distribution check

Tags: r, normal-distribution

Having a dataset like this:

```
structure(list(b1_previous = c(0.26981640312419, 0.302252978236613, 
    0.27519244423907, 0.278573602172958), b2_previous = c(0.165541492443112, 
    0.162543532408399, 0.150484069110868, 0.212810080358854), b3_previous = c(0.698096408083222, 
    0.625412783031095, 0.699099484936941, 0.610794910230257), b4_previous = c(0.156164414439798, 
    0.189265950612553, 0.151656203861282, 0.211930979296043), b5_previous = c(0.384820854982136, 
    0.364443743167243, 0.352744936715994, 0.397252245652394), b1_next = c(0.290892287578753, 
    0.279948606399405, 0.262591995672118, 0.327138300630022), b2_next = c(0.170072244074521, 
    0.190821283262141, 0.136632592108377, 0.185400160041476), b3_next = c(0.637122860008791, 
    0.595805110056691, 0.713976579846045, 0.594306130039334), b4_next = c(0.154789410213351, 
    0.185512865305938, 0.136271935262096, 0.18347290001916), b5_next = c(0.359935532588727, 
    0.391256325582968, 0.352913994612688, 0.312475345723399), before = c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L), after = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L
    ), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000003d1ef0>)
```

What kind of statistical tests could I make to see if every column follows the normal distribution?

Comment: Nothing will say any of the populations from which your data are drawn actually *have* normal distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

naming your dataset as 'data'

```
data<- structure(list(b1_previous = c(0.26981640312419, 0.302252978236613, 0.27519244423907, 0.278573602172958), 
               b2_previous = c(0.165541492443112, 0.162543532408399, 0.150484069110868, 0.212810080358854), 
               b3_previous = c(0.698096408083222, 0.625412783031095, 0.699099484936941, 0.610794910230257), 
               b4_previous = c(0.156164414439798, 0.189265950612553, 0.151656203861282, 0.211930979296043), 
               b5_previous = c(0.384820854982136, 0.364443743167243, 0.352744936715994, 0.397252245652394), 
               b1_next = c(0.290892287578753, 0.279948606399405, 0.262591995672118, 0.327138300630022), 
               b2_next = c(0.170072244074521, 0.190821283262141, 0.136632592108377, 0.185400160041476), 
               b3_next = c(0.637122860008791, 0.595805110056691, 0.713976579846045, 0.594306130039334), 
               b4_next = c(0.154789410213351, 0.185512865305938, 0.136271935262096, 0.18347290001916), 
               b5_next = c(0.359935532588727, 0.391256325582968, 0.352913994612688, 0.312475345723399), 
               before = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), 
               after = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L)),
          row.names = c(NA, -4L), 
          class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = '<pointer: 0x00000000003d1ef0>')


data<- as.data.frame(data)
my_lms <- lapply(1:ncol(data), function(x) shapiro.test(data[,x]))
summaries <- lapply(my_lms, summary)
output <- lapply(my_lms, function(x) c(x$statistic, p.value = x$p.value))
output<- as.data.frame(output)
colnames(output)<- colnames(data)
output
```

The output will be

```
        b1_previous b2_previous b3_previous b4_previous b5_previous   b1_next   b2_next   b3_next   b4_next   b5_next
W         0.8486065   0.8320889   0.8041594   0.9001520   0.9635194 0.9554072 0.8885640 0.8418775 0.8813851 0.9716332
p.value   0.2216793   0.1733145   0.1098909   0.4318145   0.8010336 0.7500127 0.3765025 0.2009322 0.3445856 0.8515698
            before      after
W       0.72863415 0.72863415
p.value 0.02385679 0.02385679
```